# Change the content images randomly

Tags: javascript

I want to randomly show the photos on my home page on the div id=content and div id=content-right. I've used the function document.getElementById('content-right'); to make my grab the div content-right img but I am unable to change the photos on the div randomly. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    Here is my HTML:
    <body>


    <div id="header">
    <ul>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <li class="logo">Liquor.com.ph</li>
      <li>Homes</li>
      <li>Offices</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      </div>
    </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="center">
    <div id="slider">


    <ul class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
          <div class="slide">
          <img src="http://sathiyam.tv/english/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/06.jpg" />
        <p class="text">Liquor.com.ph Beta</p><p class="subtext">Welcome to Liquor.com.ph</p>
            </div>
        <div class="nav">
          <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
          <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>

        </div>

        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" />
            <p class="text">Liquor.com.ph Beta</p><p class="subtext">Welcome to Liquor.com.ph</p>
            </div>
        <div class="nav">
          <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
          <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" />
              <p class="text">Liquor.com.ph Beta</p><p class="subtext">Welcome to Liquor.com.ph</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" />
           <p class="text">Liquor.com.ph Beta</p><p class="subtext">Welcome to Liquor.com.ph</p>
    </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" />
           <p class="text">Liquor.com.ph Beta</p><p class="subtext">Welcome to Liquor.com.ph</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
              <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" />
              <p class="text">Liquor.com.ph Beta</p><p class="subtext">Welcome to Liquor.com.ph</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-dots">
          <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
          <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
          <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
          <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
          <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
          <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">

    <ul>
    <p>ADS</p>
      <li><img src="http://s2.paultan.org/image/2013/06/2014-toyota-corolla-eu-0006-850x434.jpg"> </li>
      <p>ADS</p>
    <li><img src="http://s2.paultan.org/image/2013/06/2014-toyota-corolla-eu-0006-850x434.jpg"> </li>
    <p>ADS</p>
    <li><img src="http://s2.paultan.org/image/2013/06/2014-toyota-corolla-eu-0006-850x434.jpg"> </li>
    <p>ADS</p>
      <li><img src="http://s2.paultan.org/image/2013/06/2014-toyota-corolla-eu-0006-850x434.jpg"> </li>
      <p>ADS</p>
      <li><img src="http://s2.paultan.org/image/2013/06/2014-toyota-corolla-eu-0006-850x434.jpg"> </li>
      <p>ADS</p>



    </ul>


    </div>

    <div id="content-right">


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 

     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 



     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 



     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 

     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


    <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 

     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


    <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 





    </div>

      <div id="content">

     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 



     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


     <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 

         <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


    <img src="http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg" class="floatLeft">
    <h4>BOMBAY SAPPHIRE <br />DISTILLED <br />LONDON DRY GIN</h4><p class="width">The images are contained within the paragraph tag.</p> 


          </div>


      </div>




    <div id="footer">
    <h2>Liquor.com.ph</h2>
    <div id="footercontent">

    <ul class="footer1">
    <li>About us</li>
    <li>About us</li>
    <li>About us</li>
    <li>About us</li>
    <li>About us</li>
    <li>About us</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="footer2">
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="footer3">
    <li>Vision</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
    <li>Vision</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="footer5">
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="footer4">
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    <li>Mission</li>
    </ul>



    </div><!-----footer content------------------------>

    </div><!-----footer------------------------------->
    <div id='footercopy'>

    <p>Copyright 2014 &nbsp<a href="netsolutionstechnologies.com">Netsolutions Technologies</a></p>

    </div>




    <div id="img">

    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Flaming_cocktails.jpg">

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>



    Here is my CSS:
     html,body
      {
      height:100%;
      }
      body
      {
      font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      }
      h1
      {
      font-size:30px;
      }
      #img
      {
       position: fixed; 
        top: -50%; 
        left: -50%; 
        width: 200%; 
        height: 200%;
      }
      #img img
      {
       position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        margin: auto; 
        min-width: 50%;
        min-height: 50%;
      }
      #center
      {
      position:relative;
      z-index:10;
      top:0;
      background:white;
      width:960px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      min-height:1000px;
      padding:20px;
      }
      #header
      {
      position:relative;
      z-index:20;
      color:white;
      position:fixed;
      top:0;
      width:1700px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-left:-10px;
      background:silver;
      opacity:0.7;
      }
      #wrapper
      {
      width:960px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      }
      #header li
      {
      display:inline;
      padding-right:20px;
      }
      .logo
      {
      font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
      font-size:30px;
      color:blue;
      }
      /*slider*/
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);



        .slides {
        width:960px;
        padding-right:65px;
        height:420px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        z-index:11;
        }

        .slides * {
            user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        }

        .slides input { display: none; }

        .slide-container { display: block; }

        .text{
         background:silver;
         text-align:center;
         opacity:0.7;
         width:30%;
         color:white;
         position:relative;
         position:absolute;
         right:100px;
         margin-top:-400px;
         font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
         font-size:30px;
         color:blue;
        }
        .subtext
        {
         color:white; 
         font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
         font-size:30px;
         opacity:0.7;
         background:black;
         text-align:center;
         position:relative;
         position:absolute;
         right:110px;
         width:350px;
         margin-top:-260px;
        }
        .slide
        {
        top: 0;
        left:-11px;
        opacity: 0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        text-align:center;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;

            transform: scale(0);
            -moz-transform: scale(0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);

            transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
        }

        .slide img {
        margin-right:auto;
        width:960px;
        margin-left:-83px;
        margin-top:-10px;
        height:110%;
        text-align:center;

        }

        .nav label {
            width: 100px;

            display:none;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left:-35px;
            margin-right:110px;
            padding:auto;

            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 9;
            cursor: pointer;

            transition: opacity .2s;
            -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;

            color:black;
            font-size: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 380px;
            font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
        }

        .slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

        .nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

        .nav .next { right: 0; }


        input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
            opacity: 1;

            transform: scale(1);
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);

            transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        }

        input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

        .nav-dots {
            width: 960px;
            bottom: 0px;
          height: 1px;
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          text-align:center;
        }

        .nav-dots .nav-dot {
          top: -5px;
          width: 11px;
          height: 11px;

          position: relative;
          border-radius: 100%;
          display: inline-block;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        }

        .nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }

        input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
        input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
        input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
        input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
        input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
        input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          }

      /*content*/
      #content
      {
      padding-top:80px;
      width:500px;
      }
      .floatLeft 
      { 
      float:left;
      margin: 4px; 

      }
      .floatRight 
      { 
      float: right; 
      margin: 4px; 
      }
      #content img
      {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      padding:20px;
      }
      .width
      {
      width:250px;
      padding:10px 30px;
      }
      #sidebar
      {
      margin-top:50px;
      float:right;
      min-height:1500px;
      text-align:center;
      }
      #sidebar img
      {
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      }
      #sidebar li
      {
      list-style:none;
      padding:10px;

      }
      #content-right
      {
      padding-top:80px;
      width:450px;
      float:right;
      }
      #content-right img
      {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      padding:20px;
      }
      #footer
      {
       position:relative;
       z-index:100;
       left:-10px;
       width:1700px;
       clear:both;
       background:black; 
       margin-top:-23px;
       min-height:300px;
       margin-right:auto;
       margin-left:auto;
       text-align:center;
       overflow:hidden;
       opacity:0.7;
       color:white;
       font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      }
      #footercontent
      {
      width:1024px;
      font-weight:20px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      }
      .footer1 
      {
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
      padding-right:100px;
      }
      .footer2 
      {
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
      padding-right:100px;
      }
      .footer3 
      {
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
      padding-right:100px;
      }
      .footer4 
      {
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
      padding-right:100px;
      }
      .footer5
      {
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
      padding-right:100px;
      }

      #footercopy
      {
      position:relative;
      z-index:100;
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
      opacity:0.7;
      background:silver;
      color:white;
      text-align:center;
      padding:20px;
      margin-bottom:-10px;
      width:1700px;
      margin-left:-10px;
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
      }
      #footercopy a
      {
      text-decoration:none;
      color:white;
      }
      #footercopy a:hover
      {
      color:blue;
      text-decoration:underline;
      }


    Here is my Javascript:

//Javascript:
//http://jsfiddle.net/LjPLp/

//You can increase the images by adding more links to the array 


var array = ['http://acdutyfree.com/images/Page95_LiquorAndTobacco_BombaySapphire_DistilledLondonDryGin_800x800.jpg','http://images.china.cn/attachement/jpg/site1007/20130621/0013729929f1132dee4303.jpg','http://www.interaksyon.com/interaktv/assets/2014/03/gilas-vic-sotto.jpg'];
function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length;
var temporaryValue;
var randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}
var shuffled_images = shuffle(array);
var yourbackground = document.getElementById('content-right');
yourbackground.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + shuffled_images[0] + ')' ;
```

Comment: Provide your http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sQS5D/1/

Comment: This is not a way to get an element `document.getElementById('content-right img')` use `Queryselector` or Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select  your element by using `class`. like below :

```
var shuffled_images = shuffle(array);
var content_right =   document.getElementById('content-right');
var yourbackground =  content_right.getElementsByClassName('floatLeft');
 for(i=0;i<=yourbackground.length;i++){
   yourbackground[i].src =  shuffled_images  ;
 }
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/sQS5D/3/)

May this helps you ..